# How to combine multiple observables in an Ngrx effect?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

My NGRX effect does an API request and then dispatches a new action. In this new action, I need access to the initial action, **but that reference is lost after the switchMap**:

```
@Effect()
  public myAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<DoSomethingRequest>(MyActions.DO_SOMETHING),
    switchMap((action)=> this.backendService.doSomething(action.id, action.payload),
    map(dto => new DoSomethingSuccess(/* here I need both action.payload and dto */))
  );
```

**How can I keep the original action in my chain?** I need both the action and the result from the API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just restructure your chain so the original action is in the same scope as the second one:

```
@Effect()
public myAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<DoSomethingRequest>(MyActions.DO_SOMETHING),
  switchMap((action)=> this.backendService.doSomething(action.id, action.payload).pipe(
    map(dto => new DoSomethingSuccess(/* here I need both action.payload and dto */)),
  ),
);
```

In your use-case it doesn't matter if you put `map` inside or outside of `switchMap`.

Comment: Well, what do you know. Sometimes the easiest solutions are the best. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You can introduce a side effect first to store your action.

```
@Effect()
  public myAction$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<DoSomethingRequest>(MyActions.DO_SOMETHING),
    switchMap((action)=> {
      localStorage.setItem('pastAction', action);
      return this.backendService.doSomething(action.id, action.payload);
    }),
    map(dto => new DoSomethingSuccess(dto, localStorage.getItem('pastAction'))
  );
```